# Arch Linux CMake looking in wrong directory for `libxml2` dependencies

Tags: c, cmake, archlinux, zephyr-rtos

I running Arch Linux and I have the latest libxml2 package installed through pacman. When I try to build my Zephyr project with CMake I run into this error:

```
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31:10: fatal error: unicode/ucnv.h: No such file or directory
31 | #include <unicode/ucnv.h>
```

`ucnv.h` would actually be located at `../../unicode/ucnv.h` relative to `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml`, so I'm not sure why libxml2's structure was installed this way.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)

# Determine the build type
if (NOT BUILD_TYPE)
  set(BUILD_TYPE debug)
endif()

# Print out build type
message(STATUS "Build type: ${BUILD_TYPE} ")

# Set environment variables
# set(ZEPHYR_TOOLCHAIN_VARIANT gnuarmemb)
# set(GNUARMEMB_TOOLCHAIN_PATH /home/jforgue/.local/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10)

# Set auto generation notice
file(WRITE conf/version.conf "# File is autogenerated. Do not modify.\n\n")

# Get the version from Git
find_package(Git QUIET)
if(GIT_FOUND)
  execute_process(
    COMMAND git describe --tags --long
    WORKING_DIRECTORY                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE                  version
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    ERROR_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    ERROR_VARIABLE                   stderr
    RESULT_VARIABLE                  return_code
  )
  if(return_code)
    message(STATUS "git describe failed: ${stderr}; ${KERNEL_VERSION_STRING} will be used instead")
  elseif(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE)
    message(STATUS "git describe stderr: ${stderr}")
  endif()
endif()

if(version)
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^([0-9]+).*$" "\\1" version_major ${version})
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^[0-9]+\.([0-9]+).*$" "\\1" version_minor "${version}")
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.([0-9]+).*$" "\\1" version_patch "${version}")
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-([0-9]+)-.*$" "\\1" version_commit "${version}")
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+-(.*)$" "\\1" version_hash "${version}")

  # Create version.conf
  file(APPEND conf/version.conf "CONFIG_APP_VERSION_MAJOR=${version_major}\n")
  file(APPEND conf/version.conf "CONFIG_APP_VERSION_MINOR=${version_minor}\n")
  file(APPEND conf/version.conf "CONFIG_APP_VERSION_PATCH=${version_patch}\n")
  file(APPEND conf/version.conf "CONFIG_APP_VERSION_COMMIT=${version_commit}\n")
  file(APPEND conf/version.conf "CONFIG_APP_VERSION_HASH=\"${version_hash}\"\n")
  file(APPEND conf/version.conf "CONFIG_APP_VERSION=\"${version}\"\n")
  file(APPEND conf/version.conf "CONFIG_MCUBOOT_IMAGE_VERSION=\"${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_patch}+${version_commit}\"\n")

  message(STATUS "Version: ${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_patch}-${version_commit}-${version_hash}")

endif()

if(BUILD_TYPE)
  file(APPEND conf/version.conf "CONFIG_APP_RELEASE_TYPE=\"${BUILD_TYPE}\"\n")
endif()

# Define configuration files.
list(APPEND CONF_FILE
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/conf/prj.conf
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/conf/version.conf
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/conf/${BUILD_TYPE}.conf
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/boards/${BOARD}.conf
  )

# MCUboot related
list(APPEND mcuboot_OVERLAY_CONFIG
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/conf/mcuboot/mcuboot.conf"
  )

# Adding custom overlay to add settings that aren't included in the SDK (yet) for the nRF9160 Feather
if(${BOARD} STREQUAL circuitdojo_feather_nrf9160ns)
message(STATUS "Adding .overlay for mcuboot.")
list(APPEND mcuboot_DTC_OVERLAY_FILE
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/conf/mcuboot/circuitdojo_feather_nrf9160ns.overlay"
  )
endif()

find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})

project(application)

add_subdirectory(src/event_manager)
add_subdirectory(src/version)

# Include EXPAT
# find_package(EXPAT REQUIRED)
# target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC EXPAT::EXPAT)

find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC LibXml2::LibXml2)

target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.c)
```

As a side note, CMake also cant find Expat using `find_package(EXPAT REQUIRED)`. Expat is also installed through pacman.

Comment: Yes, I meant to put `../../unicode/ucnv.h` which would be `/usr/include/unicode/ucnv.h`

Comment: If `/usr/include` is on your compiler's include path, then there should be no issue for your compiler to resolve `#include <unicode/ucnv.h>` in any of the files it is compiling.  Are you cross compiling or something?  It's best to run `make VERBOSE=Y` and show us the exact GCC command that is failing so we can figure out what toolchain you are using and how your include path is set up.

Comment: If you're cross compiling, you can't just use your system's libxml2, you would have to compile it for the target system and then ensure CMake finds that version instead of the one from Arch Linux.

Comment: I see. I am trying to cross compile but I wasn't setting the correct PATH so CMake finds the correct version.